# Using AMPscript with SSJS Activities

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I have tried using the below AMPscript block in an SSJS Activity, however it appears that Script activities only support SSJS and AMPscript cannot be included in Script Activities — please can someone clarify this?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1"); 

%%[ 
SET @action = "start"
SET @id = CreateObject("ImportDefinition") 
SetObjectProperty(@id, "Name","Sonata Import") 
SetObjectProperty(@id, "AllowErrors", "true") 
SetObjectProperty(@id, "UpdateType", "Overwrite") 
SET @de = CreateObject("DataExtension") 
SetObjectProperty(@de, "CustomerKey", "InsertKeHere") 
SetObjectProperty(@id, "DestinationObject", @de) 
SetObjectProperty(@id, "FieldMappingType", "InferFromColumnHeadings") 
SetObjectProperty(@id, "FileSpec", "example-min.xml") 
SetObjectProperty(@id, "FileType", "Other") 
SetObjectProperty(@id, "Delimiter", "~") 
SET @ar = CreateObject("AsyncResponse") 
SetObjectProperty(@ar, "ResponseType", "email") 
SetObjectProperty(@ar, "ResponseAddress", "me@me.com")
SetObjectProperty(@id, "Notification", @ar) 
SET @ftl = CreateObject("FileTransferLocation") 
SetObjectProperty(@ftl, "CustomerKey", "Mercer Enhanced FTP") 
SetObjectProperty(@id, "RetrieveFileTransferLocation", @ftl) 
InvokePerform(@id, @action, @statusMessage)
]%%
<script runat="server">
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spent some time trying to figure out why @David's script is errored even if the AMPScript code is validated on a CloudPage.
Turns out it does work with Classic Content only (which already retired) and not with Content Builder.

So, to save you some time, try this code instead:

```
<script runat="server">  
var stream = Platform.Function.ContentBlockByID("YOUR_CONTENT_BLOCK_ID"); 
</script>
```

The AMPScript will be automatically be executed by the script activity.

This was tested with a Code Snippet block on Content Builder and works fine.

Answer (score 14):

I've been able to successfully write script activities that reference **AMPScript** code.  The trick is to place all your **AMPSript** code in a separate content area and call the content area from your script activity.  The script activity window can only contain **SSJS** code.

example:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
    var stream = ContentAreaByName("some-content-area-name");
    Write(TreatAsContent(stream));    
</script>
```

---

**Update:**

@KennethWagner asked how you write a script activity that will update a Salesforce object.  I've verified the above script activity does work in this scenerio.  It does require that the Salesforce Integration be configured for your account first.

To test this, I created a content area named 'some-content-area-name', which included the following code.

```
%%[
 set @ContactID = "003xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',@ContactID,'Email','david.devoy+test01@gmail.com')
]%%
```

I then created a automation to run the script activity above.  Running the script activity in an automation allow me to verify the script completed successfully.

Lastly, I verify the update by looking up the contact record in Sale Cloud.

[image]

One final point of clarification, the `Write` statement surrounding the `TreatAsContent()` function is unnecessary.  This is only helpful when testing the **SSJS** code from a landing page and coding the **AMPScript** block to actually output a value.

Comment: Using the query activity combined with AMPscript, could you copy an example of working ampscript code? I'm wondering how data is processed - if I need to use a FOR @i .... NEXT @i setup, or if it knows how to process individual records automatically?

Comment: @KennethWagner, do you mean *script activity*?  Query activities are not compatible with AMPScript.    Happy to help, but do you mind explaining your use-case a bit more?

Comment: Hi David ! Indeed, script activities. In a way i want to run some ampscript to update individual records in Salesforce. Just wondering how to structure the ampscript to make it work with your example above :-)

Comment: Hi Kenneth, I've updated the answer above with an example that uses AMPScript to update a Salesforce Object.

Comment: Hi David - Thanks for this ! :) however, the example illustrates my (potential) concern. I wouldn't be able to update a lot of different contacts.. or would i? Have you experimented with having X rows in a data extension, and then the lookup rows / for @i ... next @i ? I'm trying to figure out if I can use SSJS, ScriptActivity and AMPscript to update a lot of records in Salesforce, based on the content in a DE. New territory for me :-)

Comment: Hi Kenneth, you can most definitely place your UpdateSingleSalesforceObject() function within a for loop in order to update several contacts.  I have done this before.  I typically test out my code in a landing page.  So, I  can get some visual output.  Then I run it as a script activity when it is ready for production.

Comment: You can also have your ampscript content area act like a function by redefining the variables and calling the content area multiple times. @aspriggs has a good blog post that illustrates this.  https://sprignaturemoves.com/ca-xml/

Comment: Can I pass some value from SSJS to ampscript in content area?

Comment: I can confirm this still works and see this thread if you need it for Content Builder https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241809/ssjs-to-call-content-block-with-ampscript

And it works with Encrypt and DecryptSymmetric
Great work @DavidDevoy!

Answer (score 4):

In a landing or microsite page, sure, you can mix them, but it appears that using the same method in a **[Script Activity](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/server_side_javascript_activity/)** doesn't work.

Here was my test -- add a **Data Extension** and then create a **Subscriber**:

```
<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
    var deName = "000ASTest1";
    var deObj = {
        CustomerKey : deName,
        Name : deName,
        Fields : [
            { "Name" : "JobId", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : true },
        ]
    };
    DataExtension.Add(deObj);

</script>
%%[
  SET @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
  SetObjectProperty(@sub,"SubscriberKey","adamspriggsdeg+st1@gmail.com")
  SetObjectProperty(@sub,"EmailAddress","adamspriggsdeg+st1@gmail.com")
  SetObjectProperty(@sub,"Status","Active")

  SET @subOpt = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
  SET @saveOpt = CreateObject("SaveOption")
  SetObjectProperty(@saveOpt,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd")
  SetObjectProperty(@saveOpt,"PropertyName","*")
  AddObjectArrayItem(@subOpt,"SaveOptions",@saveOpt)

  /* update the subscriber object to true status */
  SET @stat = InvokeUpdate(@sub,@subMsg,@subErr,@subOpt)
]%%
<script runat="server">
</script>
```

It works for creating the DE, but if I add the **AMPScript**, here's what I get when I validate:

[image: ScriptTest Error]

You can do most **AMPScript** tasks with **SSJS**.  Is there a specific one you're trying to accomplish in **AMPScript** that you can't do in **SSJS**?

Comment: Adam is correct, the activity will only recognize SSJS. Anything outside what is listed as acceptable by Exact Target will throw an error. (https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/). From this page you should be able to find the SSJS version of the AMPscript you listed above.

Comment: I suppose it's a possibility to use a landing page that contains a AMPScript/SSJS hybrid script and then use the [GET()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/http_server_side_javascript_functions/) function it your Script Activity to execute it.

Comment: Thanks, trying to do `InvokePerform()` with SSJS but there's not a corresponding function for it. Will consider making a GET request.

Comment: There's an InvokePerform() SSJS function listed on this page: https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/platform_server_side_javascript_functions/accessing_api_functions_using_the_function_object/

Comment: Thanks Adam, is there an alternative for TransformXML() in SSJS?

Comment: I haven't seen any XML specific functions in SMFC SSJS.  Generally speaking, I've just used JSON objects to pass data between components.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs is there a way to pass the Data Extension name in as a variable from %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%?