# Trigger or Schedule AMPscript to run when needed. (Update on Salesforce Record)

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, ampscript, automation, landing-page

We have a working AMPscript that is hosted on a landing page that updates Salesforce records with information generated within Marketing Cloud.

Is there a way to trigger the AMPscript to run in an automatic way when needed?

We cannot use a query activity as we are actually updating a salesforce record.

Ideally we would like to know if there is a real-time and/or batch solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marketing Cloud doesn't have `AmpScript` automation activity but you can make use of [Server-Side JavaScript Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/server_side_javascript_activity/) to run timely manner in Automation studio.

Also, if it not enable in your account then reach out to support team.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! What about script activity? Does it support Ampscript or only SSJS?

Comment: It support SSJS. script activity contains your SSJS code and executes that script when started, either on its own or as part of a scheduled Automation. for more details refer https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/server_side_javascript_activity/

Comment: You can use SSJS and AMPScript together in a Script Activity.  There's an example in this answer: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/124133/5202

Answer (score 0):

While the combination of SSJS and Adam Spriggs comment about using it combined (which is awesome) would be my option of choice, if you need a hacky-solution for a small volume of data, you should be able to use the AMPscript in an email that you send to a generic email address or to e.g. the record owner and there notifying him via email. 

You would need to modify the AMPscript lookup criteria, and this will only be a recommended option for small data amount (e.g. 5 a day per record owner)