# Need total number of DataExtension Rows, SSJS only run for 2000 records

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I had a Data Extension with more than 4000 records.

In my first query I want to count all my rows in the data extension, than I want to get 10% of this amount.

> For example: 4400 records => count of 440.

Afterwards, I want to update a field in my Data Extension for only 440 subscribers. If this amount is less than 500, than I want to update another 60 subscribers.. if the count is more than 500 I want to update exactly 10%.

> For example: 6000 records => count 600

I never work with query activity and I tried the `SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT`, this work for 10% but I don't know how to count the rest to fill the amount to 500

I'm very thankful for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this AMPScript function [DataExtensionRowCount](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/dataextensionrowcount/#DataExtensionRowCount) for total row count of Data Extension and manipulate you logic with that.

Comment: SSJS Activity in Automation Studio doesn't support AMPScript.

Comment: You can use AMPscript in SSJS Script Activities, either by block reference or with TreatAsContent: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/124133/5202