# SSJS - Ampscript Function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

i read in this reply that people have successfully used Ampscript content block to perform ampscript functions that arent available within SSJS
([Using AMPscript with SSJS Activities](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99904/using-ampscript-with-ssjs-activities/124133#124133))

However what i am not sure is how i pass a value from my SSJS to the Amscript and then get the response back to continue processing. The function i am looking for isnt available in SSJS.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

We have functions called `GetValue` and `SetValue` for that, Please refer this data:
[Pass Variables from AMPscript to Server-Side JavaScript](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/use_server_side_javascript_with_ampscript/pass_variables_from_ampscript_to_server_side_javascript/)